# Add variable output value and text in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am new to PHP. I need little help. It is related to Wordpress PHP.
I have a Shortcode and a variable. I want to add the variable value inside the shortcode. Below is the code with explanation:

This is the code where I want to add variable output after `"https://"`:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[qrgen4all data="https://' . $var . '"]');?>
```

This is the variable I want to add:

```
<?php $var = $this->Shipping_Address(); ?>
```

where `$var` output is (it is a dynamic variable output):

```
"address
8422"
```

But the output is not adding after `"https://"` of the above shortcode.

Instead, If I set the variable value to `$var = "google.com"`, then it works.

Why does the first dynamic variable `"$var = $this->Shipping_Address()"` value is not adding after `"https://"` in the shortcode?

Comment: Try removing the line break, or is it a `<br>`

Comment: _Little Note_ If the $var contains `address 8422` then that is going to be meaningless following a `https://` as what does `https://address 8422` mean? Not much as likely as not

Comment: Can you post an example of a real output of `$var`? I'm not quite sure if you're communicating what exactly the output of `$var` is

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I want to make a direct map URL with that address. It will be meaningful at the end.

Comment: @John , [link](https://imgur.com/a/1Mof0m8) is the output.

Comment: @John I think the variable output need to be clean. The value may contain something. Is there any way to convert the variable output to something else and then store it to another variable and add with the "https://" ?

Comment: Try this to clean it up: `$newvar = str_replace(['"',"'","<br>"], "", $var);` then replace `$var` in the shortcode with `$newvar`